# How to ignore non existent keys when transforming json with Play Json

Tags: json, scala, playframework

The code below results in an exception when e.g. source.foo key does not exist in `json`. `java.util.NoSuchElementException: JsError.get`

I'm trying to transform json using dynamically selected sequence of Reads (I called them transformers).

**How can I ignore non existent fields? i.e. not write anything to the transformed json for the keys that don't exist in the source json?**

```
  val iconTransformer = (__ \ 'res \ 'foo).json.copyFrom ((__ \ 'source \ 'foo).json.pick)

  val ppTransformer = (__ \ 'res \ 'bar).json.copyFrom((__ \ 'source \ 'bar).json.pick)

  val transformers = Seq(iconTransformer, ppTransformer)

  val combined = transformers.reduce((a, b) => (a and b).reduce)

  json.transform(combined)
```

Comment: Wrap those fields in `Option`.

Comment: This is a great example of why I find play-json very frustrating.  There's probably a very nice, clean way to do this, but good luck figuring it out.  If you can't find it, drop back and create a Reads (transformer) for one transform (e.g. iconTransformer) using simple unlifted code, then generalize from it.  Sorry I can't be more specifically helpful - no time.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a reader and then use `validate` to make sure an element is actually present:

```
val json = { ... }

val nameReads: Reads[String] = (JsPath \ "name").read[String]

val nameResult: JsResult[String] = json.validate[String](nameReads)

nameResult match {
  case s: JsSuccess[String] => println("Name: " + s.get)
  case e: JsError => println("Errors: " + JsError.toFlatJson(e).toString()) 
}
```

Check out the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaJsonCombinators), specifically "Validation with Reads".

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but here's one approach, left a bit verbose for clarity:

```
  object iconTransformer extends Reads[JsObject] {
    def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[JsValue] =
      (json \  "source" \ "foo") match {
        case _:JsUndefined => JsSuccess(json)
        case jsValue:JsValue =>
          json.transform((__ \ 'res \ 'foo).json.put(jsValue))
    }
  }
```

It's pretty ugly, but it would be easy to encapsulate the ugly bits for reuse.
I expect there's a much simpler way - I just don't know it.